# When do Android EditText's requestFocus()

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext

I have a number of EditTexts inside a scrollview. In the background these fields are linked to a number of other fields and regularly (once a second or so) the layout has it's textfields updated depending on the values in the EditText.

The problem is if one EditText has focus at the top of the ScrollView and the user scrolls the view done (i.e. so the focused EditText is off screen), but if the update is made to the views, the scroll view moves up to focus on the EditText at the top of the view.

The closest I have got to remedying this is to make the scroll view change focus when scrolling however this is still has the same behaviour but at a reduced scale.

Does anyone have an idea of how I can stop this from happening?

Cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `EditText#setFocusable` around your code that updates the value. I haven't tested this but if the problem is that it is getting focus when you use `setText()` it may help.

Comment: I gave this ago and worked to some degree. But when I re-enable focus the scrollview still moves to that few, to some degree I want the scrollview to ignore the focus requests of the EditText's unless the EditText is touched.